# jQueryUI tabs render but don't work

Tags: umbraco, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using jQueryUI tabs as part of an Umbraco page. Here's the core HTML for that page:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="body" ID="ContentBody" runat="server">
    <cc1:UmbracoPanel runat="server" Height="224px" Width="412px" hasMenu="false" meta:resourcekey="PageTitle">
        <div style="padding: 2px 15px 0px 15px">
            <div class="dashboardWrapper">
                <div id="tabs">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="tabs-1">
                        <p>Tab 1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tabs-2">
                        <p>Tab 2</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tabs-3">
                        <p>Tab 3</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </cc1:UmbracoPanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Although the tabs are rendered, the content of all the tabs can be seen in tab 1. When clicking other tabs, such as tab 2 or 3, the content does not change. It's as though the clicking of the tabs do nothing.

I've double-checked the HTML and I don't believe that anything is amiss, such as the `id` values of the `div` elements differ to those expected in the corresponding `a` tags, but I cannot see what is wrong.

EDIT
Ah, forgot the jQuery :)

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/umbraco_client/application/jquery/jquerytabs.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/umbraco_client/ui/jqueryui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
        })
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Can you post the jquery code you are invoking.

Comment: Your markup does not contain a reference to your jQuery UI theme CSS file, which might explain the issue. Unless `/umbraco_client/application/jquery/jquerytabs.css` is supposed to replace it?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I will look into that, didn't spot it myself. I did try using a custom .js file specifically just with the tabs code, hence the corresponding .css file. I'll look for the usual Umbraco CSS file instead.

Comment: I tried looking for the .css file that Umbraco uses for tabs. It doesn't help that all the .css files are named "style.css". Stupid. Anyway I found "tabview\style.css" and linked that into my page. The result is that the tabs do not render at all now. I'll keep looking into this.